# unitary matrix times its transpose equals identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A complex square matrix U is unitary if its conjugate transpose $U^*$ is also its inverse – that is, if $U^*U=UU^*=I$, where I is the identity matrix.

Question is:$UU^T=I$ or not?

Comment: Only if the matrix has real entries

Answer (score 1):

It is not true even when $n=1$. Take $U = (i)$ be the $1\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: If $ {u_1,u_2,...,u_n} $ is orthonormal basis of $R^n$, is it true?

Comment: Yes if you mean $U = (u_1\ \ u_2\ \ \cdots u_n)$. @VivianZhang